# Session Timeout Logout :: RouterExtensions errors when called by setTimeout

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to implement a session timeout when idle for a certain time period.

When the user logs in I'm starting a timer that will log the user out after a time interval and route them back to the login form.

If there is an event (tap) I want to clear the timer (5 seconds here) and start a new timer, thereby keeping the user logged in.

Here is the setTimout call in login.component.ts:

```
var timeoutId=setTimeout(this.funcService.logout, 5000);
ApplicationSettings.setNumber("timeoutId", timeoutId);
```

Here is func.service.ts that has the logout function.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterExtensions} from "nativescript-angular/router";
import * as ApplicationSettings from "@nativescript/core/application-settings";

@Injectable({   providedIn: 'root' })
export class FuncService {
    
  constructor(
    private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions
  ) {
  }

  logout(): void {

    ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", false);
    ApplicationSettings.remove("token");

    this.routerExtensions.navigate(["./login"], {clearHistory: true});
  }  
}
```

app.component.html

```
<page-router-outlet actionBarVisibility="never" (tap)=onEvent()></page-router-outlet>
```

app.component.ts

```
 onEvent() {
    var timeoutId=ApplicationSettings.getNumber("timeoutId");

    ApplicationSettings.remove("timeoutId");

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);

    var timeoutId=setTimeout(this.funcService.logout, 5000);
    ApplicationSettings.setNumber("timeoutId", timeoutId);
  }
```

When the timer runs down and `this.funcService.logout` is called I get the error:

```
JS: ### ErrorHandler Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'routerExtensions' of undefined
JS: ### ErrorHandler Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'routerExtensions' of undefined
JS:     at webpackHotUpdate../shared/func.service.ts.FuncService.logout (file:///app\shared\func.service.ts:35:9)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:421:0)
JS:     at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:24328:0)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:420:0)
JS:     at Zone.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.Zone.runTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:188:0)
JS:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (file:///data/...
```

If I call `this.funcService.logout`explicitly I get no error.

Any idea what is happening here so I can get around it?

Is this an OK way to implement this?

TIA

Note: I have also tried using the router

```
this.router.navigate(["./login"], {
  relativeTo: this.activatedRoute
});
```

Getting

```
S: ### ErrorHandler Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
JS: ### ErrorHandler Stack: TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
JS:     at module.exports.push../shared/func.service.ts.FuncService.logout (file:///app\shared\func.service.ts:38:9)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:421:0)
JS:     at Object.onInvokeTask (file:///node_modules\@angular\core\fesm5\core.js:24328:0)
JS:     at ZoneDelegate.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:420:0)
JS:     at Zone.push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.Zone.runTask (file:///node_modules\@nativescript\angular\zone-js\dist\zone-nativescript.js:188:0)
JS:     at push.../node_modules/@nativescript/angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (file:///data/data/com.FileExpenses.app/files/app/v...
```

UPDATE

This worked

```
var timeoutId=setTimeout(() => {

  ApplicationSettings.setBoolean("authenticated", false);
  ApplicationSettings.remove("token");

  this.routerExtensions.navigate(["./login"], {clearHistory: true});
}, 5000);
```

Thanks @Yong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix undefined routerExtensions

```
var timeoutId=setTimeout(() => this.funcService.logout, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks @Yong I tried this and it does not call the function on timeout. However if I put the logout code into the setTimeout it does work as I added onto the end of my post. Not sure why the function call to this.funcService.logout isn't firing.